# How to install telegram-cli with Persian/Arabic support

Tags: command-line, packaging, snap, telegram

I want to install `telegram-cli` in Ubuntu 17.04 AMD64. So I use this commands:

```
sudo snap install telegram-cli
```

But it not support Persian/Arabic letters. All Persian/Arabic letters has been messed up. And I can't type any Persian/Arabic characters.

And here is the question, How can I solve this problem.

Comment: take into account that telegram-cli hasn't been touched in the last year. It seems abandoned: https://github.com/vysheng/tg/commits/master

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue has two reason, first one is `gnome-terminal` not supported Persian. And the second one is `snap` not supported Persian.

You can solve this problem, with this ways:

**First way (easy way):**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ali.r/telegram-cli
sudo apt update
sudo apt install telegram-cli
```

This PPA has packages for Ubuntu `16.04`, `17.04`, `17.10`. And install `konsole` alongside of `telegram-cli`, which is support Persian language.

So you can run `konsole` and then run `telegram-cli` on it. As you can see it support Persian completely.

**Second way (hard way):**

Install dependency:

```
sudo apt install konsole make git libreadline-dev libconfig-dev libssl-dev lua5.2 liblua5.2-dev lua-lgi libevent-dev libjansson-dev libpython-dev
```

Download sources from github:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/vysheng/tg.git
```

Configure and compile it:

```
cd tg
./configure
make
```

And make a symbolic link to its binary:

```
sudo ln /bin/telegram-cli /usr/local/bin
```

And you can use `telegram-cli` easily in `konsole` for Persian support.

**Optional:**

You can make a launcher for this package.

So run this command:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/telegramcli.desktop
```

And paste this contents to that file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Telegram Cli
Comment=Command-line interface for Telegram messenger
Exec=konsole --noclose -e 'telegram-cli --enable-msg-id'
Icon=terminal
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=TelegramCli
Type=Application
Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;Qt;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/tg;
```

And run this command:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/share/applications/telegramcli.desktop
```

So you can run telegram-cli from applications menu.